# Element breaks flow in multi-column layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, multiple-columns, retina-display

I've ran into an issue that seems to be specific to Chrome on a device with retina display. Specifically, I'm using:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012)
- OS X (10.10.2)
- Chrome (40.0.2214.111) (64-bit)

---

I've created a CSS multi-column layout on a `<ul>` element, where one of the `<li>`'s contains a `<div>`, which has `max-height: 50px` and `overflow: auto`.

Instead of acting as you'd expect, the `<div>` seemingly ignores the columns and places itself where it would be if there were no columns at all, e.g., https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3x1A.png.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pabwszej/2/ (resize the result window so you get a 3-column layout)

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand the question... Is this kind of what you are expecting as it displaying? http://jsfiddle.net/pabwszej/3/

Comment: @JoePacker Yeah, that's exactly it! So I just needed the `-webkit-column-width` on the `<li>` instead of the `<ul>`. Nice one, cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear! Please approve the below answer so others can see it easily.  Thanks! @Will

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

[jsfiddle.net/pabwszej/3](http://jsfiddle.net/pabwszej/3)

```
ul, li {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

div { max-height: 50px; overflow: scroll; border: 1px solid green; }

.columns {  }

.columns > li { margin-bottom: 5px; border: 1px solid red; -webkit-column-width: 150px; width:150px; float:left; margin-left:5px; }
```